# What is the regular expression for the set of all strings of 0's and 1's whose tenth symbol from the right end is 1?

Tags: regex

I found that the answer is (0+1)* (0+1)^9 but I don't understand the logic of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is:

`[01]*1[01]{9}`

`[01]` is a set of symbols to match against, this matches `0` or `1`.
`*` says match zero or more times
`1` is the 10th one from the right
`[01]{9}` is as above, but `{9}` is a quantifier which needs 9 matches.

A maybe better one could be

`^[01]*1[01]{9}$`

where `^` is the beginning of the line, and `$` the end of the line, so that there are other characters except the zero and ones.

Answer (score -1):

One answer could be `(0+1)*1(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)`.  Here, right ninth symbols are explicitly written.